# PHP's error log showing StackOverflow related errors

Tags: support

I've recently checked my Apache's error log, and I found some interesting things in there:

```
[Mon Aug 29 12:04:06 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/Websites/htdocs/quant.js, referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-the-php-error-log-reside-in-xampp
[Mon Aug 29 12:04:06 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: D:/Websites/htdocs/ga.js, referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-the-php-error-log-reside-in-xampp
```

It seems that you have some relative linking that should be absolute, (or reformatted better?)

Any comments on this one?

Comment: You've got quite big trouble. But I have no idea where this appears. There's nothing in HTML source. When you access it, do you have more errors like this?

Comment: When I access it it does indeed redirect to my own localhost (and returns a 404 error of course, as I don't have these files)

Comment: Ouch, -5? That hurts you know :(

Comment: it's not that bad. I have asked question which was -22

Comment: Question shouldn't be closed.  It just helped me.  Many people block ads on webpages in the manner mentioned in the accepted answer.  ...seems like at least the 9 people who upvoted the answer thought it was useful

Comment: @Gerrat: It being closed doesn't make it unavailable to anyone. If it were deleted though, that would be a different story.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have probably mapped those domain names (QuantCast and Google Analytics respectively) to 127.0.0.1 in your local hosts file, therefore your browser is trying to retrieve them locally.

Not our problem.

Comment: I only have 2 uncommented lines in my hosts file and they are not related to neither. I have nothing there redirecting to localhost anyway.

Comment: could be ad block or "privacy" software. Try on a clean OS install in a fresh browser.

Comment: An ad block is a possiblity as I am using one, I'll try and see :)\